# usb read only after formatting

Tags: usb, readonly

I have formatted a USB flash drive,  but when I try to move files from somewhere (or create one) into it, it tells me "Destination is read-only". However, I already tryied to `chmod 777 /media/denis/USB` but this doesn't work? The problem persists whatever the USB's file system is (I tried NTFS, FAT32 and EXT4)

The only way to put files in it is to use `sudo cp from to`. Clearly, this suck I would like to use my mouse when moving files into USB.

System: Linux Mint 18.0, USB flash is only 1week old; before had Mint ISO in it, but formatted after that.

Answer (score 4):

Was there an OS prior to the re-format?, like a Linux Live distro? If so, especially if it was GPT, the boot flag is probably set.

If you moved the USB stick over to a Windows 10 PC and formatted it msdos, which is seen as FAT32 in Linux, the USB stick probably now has a Volume descriptor folder in it. After formatting it under Windows 10 you will need to format it under Linux to get rid of the Volume descriptor folder, which is seen as a 'key' under gparted.

Reformat the USB stick under Linux as FAT32 and it should now be possible to copy files normally. If it was formatted as UEFI/GPT then you may have to run 'fixparts' to remove the GPT table and write out an MBR.

Answer (score 1):

First off, mounting of any form is a privileged Linux operation.  Thus you need root to mount your USB drive.

HOWEVER, if you put an entry into your `/etc/fstab` file like:

```
 /dev/sdb   /mnt     ext4    noauto,users
```

And ensure the perms of `/mnt` are 777.  Then any non-root user can mount and unmount the USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

Do
`sudo fdisk -l`
Look for your USB by searching the drive having the same size as your USB key. So if you have for example a 16GB USB key, there should be something like */dev/sdb1 - 15GB*. Once you know which one it is try this:
`sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb`
Just replace the */dev/sdb* with the identifier your USB key uses.

If that doesn't work, open gParted, select the correct drive (be careful of that) and Select *Device > Create Partition Table* and then select *msdos* and click *Apply* (It will erase all your data on the stick!).
Then format the drive to FAT32.

Comment: this didn't worked.
The USB was partitioned successfully, once mounter, the owner was root. I changed owner, and the contextual menu (when you right-click inside usb folder)  "Create New Folder" / "Create New Document"  is now available, but I am still getting the same error, and the only way to create /  add new file, is through the shell.

Comment: Do other disks or USB storage devices work? If this is a general problem, try to use another *File Manager* for this reason. Also you can try to open the *File Manager* as root and see if you still can't move files per *GUI*.

Comment: Open File Manager with sudo works :)

Comment: Did you check in the folder properties if the *chmod 777* really worked? Maybe it is still owned by *root*.

Comment: I just retried, and no, the _chmod 777_ nor _chown_ dont work. They produce effect (rights/owner are changed) but this doesn't allow me to add new files. still need sudo to do it

Comment: Open the terminal, type `cd /media/denis/` then type `ls -alt`. Update the answer with your output.

Comment: /media/denis
`drwxr-xr-x  5 denis root 4.0K Mar 21 08:38 usb`
/dev
`brw-rw----  1 root  disk      8,  16 Mar 21 08:47 sdb
brwxrwxrwx  1 denis disk      8,  17 Mar 21 08:47 sdb1`

Comment: Which one is your USB Stick?

Comment: hum well SDB is the USB, and SDB1 is the 1st partition in it

Comment: That shouldn't be like it. Try to `chown -cR denis:denis xx` replacing *xx* with the folder names in the */denis/* folder. Add the output to your question, so it is more easily readable.